# Stripe - Subscription + Upfront fee using PaymentIntent

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a question regarding Stripe and the new PaymentIntent functionality.

Our platform allows connected accounts to setup subscriptions for their customers (we use Stripe Connect).
Sometimes the connected accounts collect an upfront fee along with the subscription.

With the new PaymentIntent functionality:

How do I collect both an upfront fee and setup the subscription (and collect the initial payment of the subscription) at the same time?

I have tried to setup a PaymentIntent, which first collects the upfront fee and then subscribe the customer afterwards. It does collect the upfront fee, however, when I subscribe the customer to the plan, it gives an error - something in the lines of: 'PaymentMethod already used', which is because the PaymentIntent has already been used to collect the upfront fee.

Do I need to setup two separate Intents: one SetupIntent (for setting up the subscription) and one PaymentIntent (to handle the upfront fee)?

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: I think you're approaching this from slightly the wrong direction. I'd suggest simply adding an invoice item to the customer : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#first-invoice-extra and then create the subscription https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment . That will charge the upfront fee and start the subscription. If that initial payment requires authentication, the Subscription is `incomplete` and you can work with the PaymentIntent from its first invoice like described in the link. You don't need to create any PaymentIntents or SetupIntents yourself.

Comment: I couldn't try yet. But your suggestions will be great for me.  Thank You